# How do I get back into my bitcoin core wallet JSON format no data file

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, electrum

I had 2 wallets long time ago mined on bitcoin core can’t remember JSON that well or what my wallet descriptors was. I did use bip 39 but not giving me my addresses back on electrum wallet please help I have a p2pkh

---

There’s other ways in I just don’t remember right off hand yet. But I do know I might of backed it up on blockchain but it’s been along time ago and don’t remember the steps

Answer (score 2):

> Bitcoin Core wallet **JSON** Format

Are you sure it was Bitcoin Core? Bitcoin Core doesn't store the wallet in [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), it typically stores wallet data in a file named `wallet.dat` which has a non-text data format (Berkeley DB, but some other data files are LevelDB). See [What do the different .dat files contain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/853/13866)

You can produce JSON output from Bitcoin Core's command Line Interpreter (CLI) but that wouldn't be an actual wallet.

There are other wallet programs that store wallet data in JSON. For example version 2 of Electrum.

---

> I did use **bip 39**

Bitcoin Core does not support BIP 39 - See [Is there a reason to why Bitcoin Core does not implement BIP39?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/88237/13866)

Early versions of Electrum had a different seed-phrase system but you can use BIP 39 with current versions of Electrum so long as you first tell Electrum that the seed-phrase uses the BIP 39 system.

You can check your phrase against various word lists to help identify it. See [Identify Wallet based upon word phrase](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/111442/13866)

---

> not giving me my addresses back on **electrum** wallet

You also need to make sure you are using the same "derivation path" that the original wallet used. See [Default derivation paths](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78993/13866)

You might also need to increase the "gap limit". See [Bitcoin address gap limit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/111534/13866)

---

> I might of backed it up on **blockchain**

If you mean the blockchain.com business, You'd have to talk to them about recovery. See [16 word recovery phrase for blockchain wallet not working](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/68546/13866) as well as [I have forgotten my Blockchain account password and 12 word recovery. I have the wallet id and password to the wallet. Can i get my funds back?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101310/13866)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the P2PKH (the public address) you won't be able to access it anymore.

Bitcoin Core stores wallet information in a .dat file. If you retrieve this file you could restore it in a fresh Bitcoin Core installation. The .dat file is located in "Bitcoin Core installation folder/YourWalletLabel/wallet.dat".

If you uninstalled Bitcoin core a while ago and didn't save that anywhere, I'm afraid the account is forever lost.